# Tensor product of preordered rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, quadratic-forms, tensor-products, ordered-fields, real-algebra

All rings in this post are commutative, unital, and contain $\frac{1}{2}$.

To study "real" properties of a ring $R$, one is often interested in the orderings which exist on  fraction fields of quotients of $R$ by prime ideals. This naturally leads to the definition of a preordering on a ring.

A *preordering* on a ring $R$ is a subset $T \subseteq R$ such that $T + T \subseteq T, T \cdot T \subseteq T$ and $\lbrace x \in R \mid \exists y \in R : x = y^2 \rbrace \subseteq T$. The *support* of a preordering $T$ is defined to be $T \cap -T$; one can show that this is an ideal of the ring $R$. A preordering can be extended to an ordering on the fraction field of $R/(T \cap -T)$.

If $(R_1, T_1)$ and $(R_2, T_2)$ are preordered rings extending a common preordered subring $(R, T)$, their push-out in the category of preordered rings is the ring $(R_1 \otimes_R R_2, T_1 \otimes T_2)$ where
$$
T_1 \otimes_R T_2 = \left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^m (t_i \otimes_R t_i')x_i^2 \middle| m \in \mathbb{N}, t_i \in T_1, t' \in T_2, x_i \in R_1 \otimes_R R_2 \right\rbrace.
$$
**Question:** What can one say about the support of $T_1 \otimes_R T_2$? Certainly it contains the ideal $\text{supp}(T_1) \otimes_R R_2 + R_1 \otimes_R \text{supp}(T_2)$, but do we have equality? In the case $R$ is a field it follows from standard results on the amalgamation of ordered fields that $\text{supp}(T_1 \otimes_R T_2)$ is contained in some minimal prime ideal lying over $\text{supp}(T_1) \otimes_R R_2 + R_1 \otimes_R \text{supp}(T_2)$ (assuming the latter is not equal to $R_1 \otimes_R R_2$), but even in this caseù where $R$ is a field, I would like to have a more explicit description.

Comment: Your definitions/terminology are a little unusual. You have added to the usual axioms for (pre-)ordered ring that the positive cone contain all sums of squares. Moreover, I wouldn't call $T \cap -T$ the support---rather it behaves more like a radical, in that you want to factor it out. There is a relevant result in the literature: if we add the property that $1$ be an order unit and drop the sums of squares requirement, then the tensor product of two ordered rings is again an ordered ring. So in that case equality occurs.

Comment: Indeed the condition on squares being positive is what makes the problem hard, although I thought it arose quite naturally if one thinks of preorderings as "seeds" of orderings on the fraction field obtained after factoring out the support/radical. Definitions are taken from Markus Schweighofer's course notes ([link](https://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~schweigh/17/real-alg-geo-16-17.pdf)).

Is there a freely accessible reference for the result you mention?

Comment: It used to be that Can J Math had no paywall; but now that Cambridge has taken it over, there seems to be a paywal (Cambridge is worse than Elsivier, if that's possible). Goodearl, K., & Handelman, D. (1986). Tensor Products of Dimension Groups and K 0 of Unit-Regular Rings. Canadian Journal of Mathematics, 38(3), 633-658. doi:10.4153/CJM-1986-032-0